# Changing the type of primitive arrays in Java

Tags: java, generics, types, casting, primitive-types

I have a numeric program in Java that does a lot of operations on primitive arrays.  I use primitive arrays (`double[]`/`float[]`/`int[]`) because they are much more memory and time-efficient than dealing with arrays of pointers to values (e.g. `ArrayList<Float>`).

Now, I want to be able to change my primitive type, eg. from double to float, based on some parameter to my program.  But since primitive can not be used as generics, I can't for the life of me figure out how.

Is there any way, or is the vast amount of code replication or casting I have to do just an unavoidable flaw of Java?

Comment: Sorry, no way. That's why there is so many repeating code in overloaded `Arrays.sort()` implementations.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use one of those less time efficient collections, and wrap it in a class that provides the functionality to convert between types.

Comment: If you don't have methods specific to the generic type parameter (doWithInt, doWithFloat, etc), have you considered Collection<Number> (to avoid needing the conversion)?

Comment: Collection<Number> requires that I use a wrapper class (Float/Double/Integer).  This is inefficient because it means storing an array of pointers to values instead of an array of values.

Comment: don't be afraid of using code generation.... no big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to deal with primitive types only? If not, you could consider having an array of Number - this way you can instantiate either a Float[] or Double[].

```
Number numbers[] = (param == "float" ? new Float[n] : new Double[n]);
```

I assume using wrappers is less efficient than using primitives (I haven't benchmarked though) but it's sure faster than using Collections (eg ArrayList).

Comment: So the whole point of me wanting to do this is for efficiency.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but wrapper arrays contain a 64-bit address for every value (16, 32 or 64 bits).  So they are definitely a lot less memory efficient and as a result (depending on cache size) less time efficient too.

Comment: In this case I'm afraid you are left with no option other than either doing tons of casts or having multiple methods that do the same operation on different types (doThisOnFloat, doThisOnDouble, etc). I don't think primitive types are meant to be this flexible - wrappers are.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible implementation of a wrapper class:

```
public class NumberListWrapper<T extends Number> {
    private ArrayList<T> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    public boolean add(T num) {
        return numbers.add(num);
    }

    public boolean contains(T num) {
        return numbers.contains(num);
    }

    public boolean remove(T num) {
        return numbers.remove(num);
    }

    public float[] toFloatArray() {
        float[] floats = new float[numbers.size()];

        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
            floats[i] = numbers.get(i).floatValue();
        }

        return floats;
    }
}
```

Other primitive array conversions use the same pattern as this float one.

Edit: You probably want a get() method too... lol